# SQL code to add between Asks

Tags: sql, date, addition

I'm trying to add values between two two rows order by date. Specifically the rows are defined by having the same ID and a type of "ASK"

I need:

- add the Amt value where Type = Gift between two Asks by ID#, ordered by Date
- or until there are no more asks.

Here's the data in the table:

```
ID  Date    Type    Amt
1   1/1/15  Ask     100
2   2/1/15  Ask     200
1   3/1/15  Gift    25
1   4/1/15  Gift    100
2   5/1/15  Gift    50
1   6/1/15  Ask     300
1   7/1/15  Gift    100
2   8/1/15  Gift    100
2   9/1/15  Ask     200
```

EDIT:

data order by ID, Date

```
| ID |       Date | Type | Amt |
|----|------------|------|-----|
|  1 | 2015-01-01 |  Ask | 100 |
|  1 | 2015-03-01 | Gift |  25 |
|  1 | 2015-04-01 | Gift | 100 |
|  1 | 2015-06-01 |  Ask | 300 |
|  1 | 2015-07-01 | Gift | 100 |
|  2 | 2015-02-01 |  Ask | 200 |
|  2 | 2015-05-01 | Gift |  50 |
|  2 | 2015-08-01 | Gift | 100 |
|  2 | 2015-09-01 |  Ask | 200 |
```

I need my results to look like this:

```
ID  Ask Amt Gift Amt
1   100     125
2   200     150
1   300     100
2   200
```

The result shows for each ask by an ID the total amount of gifts before the next ask of the ID.

Comment: Why is the `ID` column not unique? What does it represent?

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Dai Looks like (ID, Date) is compound key. Anyway still `EAV` design

Comment: You need include a more detail logic explanation. I dont know where come `125 Amt`. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @lad2025  actually, it's most probablt (ID, date, Type)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it's simply the sum of all Gift Amount between each "Ask", grouped by IDs

Comment: @JulienBlanchard Yes, but what ID?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza well... the column named ID? It's a simple request using a window function grouped by ID and where type = Ask.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard Dont know, I just edit to read better, Looks like is there some jump conditional

Comment: I don't understand you say in the question you need to total between two dates, but the logic of what you are doing shows you are adding up values of type gift between two ask types

Comment: @Hogan I include the data sort the by ID, Date, now have a litle more sense.

Comment: Why are there two rows for each id in the output?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because there are two asks for each

Answer (score 2):

Lets take it step by step.

If we ignore the hard part for now (total up the gives) and just try to return to first two columns of your expected output we have a query that looks like this:

```
 SELECT ASK.ID, ASK.Date, ASK.Amt as "Ask Amt"
 FROM yourtable as ASK
 WHERE Type = 'Ask'
 ORDER BY Date
```

I've included date because we need that later.

Now we have the first two columns, what is the 3rd column?  It is the sum of gift amounts in range.

We need a date range to find these.  We can use LEAD() window function to do this (in SQL Server, DB2 and Oracle).  Remember we are only looking at the "ASK" type in this query so the next one (the lead) is the end of our range.

```
 SELECT ASK.ID, ASK.Date as S_Date, 
        LEAD(ASK.Date) OVER (Partition By ID ORDER BY Date) AS E_Date, ASK.Amt as "Ask Amt"
 FROM yourtable as ASK
 WHERE Type = 'Ask'
 ORDER BY Date
```

Finally we take this query and join it back to the table and do a group by and a sum to get our results

```
 SELECT sub.ID, sub.Ask_Amt, SUM(G.Amt) AS Give_Amt
 FROM (
   SELECT ASK.ID, ASK.Date as S_Date, 
          LEAD(ASK.Date) OVER (Partition By ID ORDER BY Date) AS E_Date, ASK.Amt as Ask_Amt
   FROM yourtable as ASK
   WHERE Type = 'Ask'
 ) sub
 LEFT JOIN yourtable as G ON G.Type = 'Gift' 
                    AND G.Date >= sub.S_Date
                    AND G.Date <= COALESCE (sub.E_Date,G.Date)
                    AND sub.ID = G.ID
 GROUP BY sub.ID, sub.Ask_Amt, sub.S_Date
```

Working Fiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a87e/12

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- fixed

Comment: The sad aprt about that is the fact that a few DBMS don't implement windows functions (like MS SQL 2008 for instance). This means the LEAD function wouldn't be usable. And we still don't know the DBMS.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard - it has only been 43 mins... maybe he was called into a meeting

Comment: @JulienBlanchard he wrote on lad2005 answer but he delete, so not sure what he say.

Comment: He said: `Thank you for you response! Sorry I'm unclear, I'm not entirely sure how to state my problem in a more clear way. Anyway, I'm using SQL Navigator and I know there are some constraints with this software, but I believe I've tried similar code to what you've suggested. The problem I'm having is this adds ups all the amounts where type = 'Gift' past the next 'Ask'. I just want it to add the amounts until it get's to another Ask and not add the Gifts past that. Does this make sense?`

Comment: @lad2025 -- I understood his problem and did what he asked.  He should read my answer since it solves the problem.  It amazes me that he could not wait 30 mins for an answer.  Makes me wish I did not spend the time to write it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- see addition of `LEFT` to join and `sub.S_Date` to group by.  Should work now.

Comment: dont worry.  I read it and learn from it, you didnt waste your time :)

Comment: @Hogan and everyone, thank you all for you answer, input, questions back, and comments. After manipulating it to fit into SQL Navigator (which as I said before has major limitations) I got it to work! I have been working on this problem for so long that I was just going in circles so THANK YOU again everyone for your expertise! I thought I needed to use an over partition by in some way but I could not figure it out! This was my first time posting a question on here and you were all great at helping me solve my problem.

Comment: @MaryMack - The technical name for it is "windowing function" since it looks at a "window" of a single field in the set of rows.